# UICollectionViewCell to show detail view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Here is image for my project:https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlk9a.jpg

When I click in `UICollectionViewCell`, it will show a small detail view like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6sv9.jpg

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

}
```

How can I get this to work, please help me!

Update link to my project:
https://github.com/VMTrinh/EmojiFunction

Comment: No! I want show a view detail was created by UIView

Comment: As you show in your project image, you have it working, right? The background green view is the one that is appearing after you tap the dog emoji.. or does the view just loads that way and nothing happens when tapping cells from the collection view?